# Как получить значение переменных из каждого отдельного объекта. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Выполняю задание на объектно-ориентированное программирование,в котором столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно фиксировать столкновение фигур, но я не знаю как получить значение каждого отдельного объекта, т.е координаты.

```
// Цель: нарисовать три фигуры:
// красный прямоугольник, который двигается вертикально
// зеленый круг, который двигается горизонтально
// синий квалрат, который двигается по диагонали и вращается

// Решение: изменим только Square

class Figure {

    constructor() {
        this.positionX = 0;
        this.positionY = 0;
    }

    draw() {}

    move() {
        this.moveLeft = false;
        this.moveUp = false;
    }
    
}

class Rect extends Figure { // наследование
    draw() {
        // полиморфизм
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += `
            <div style="
                background: red;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                top: ${this.positionY}px;
                left: ${this.positionX}px;"></div>
            `;
    }

    move() {
        switch(this.positionX) {
            case 450: 
                this.moveLeft = true;
                break;
            
            case 0:
                this.moveLeft = false;
                break;
        }

        switch(this.positionY) {

            case 250:
                    this.moveUp = true;
                    break;

                case 0:
                    this.moveUp = false;
                    break;
        }

        this.moveLeft ? this.positionX -= 1 : this.positionX += 1;
        this.moveUp ? this.positionY -= 5 : this.positionY += 5;
    }
}


class Circle extends Figure { // наследование
    draw() {
        // полиморфизм
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += `
            <div style="
                background: green;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: ${this.positionX}px"></div>
        `;
    }

    move() {
        switch(this.positionX) {
            case 800: 
                this.moveLeft = true;
                break;
            
            case 0:
                this.moveLeft = false;
                break;
        }
        this.moveLeft ? this.positionX -= 50 : this.positionX += 50;
        
    }
}

class Square extends Figure {
    constructor() {
        super(); // вызов родительского конструктора
        this.rotation = 0;
    }

    draw() {
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += `
            <div style="
                background: blue;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                transform: rotate(${this.rotation}turn);
                top: ${this.positionY}px;
                left: ${this.positionX}px"></div>
        `;
    }

    move() { // переопределение метода
        switch(this.positionX) {
            case 800: 
                this.moveLeft = true;
                break;
            
            case 0:
                this.moveLeft = false;
                break;
        }

        switch(this.positionY) {

            case 500:
                    this.moveUp = true;
                    break;

                case 0:
                    this.moveUp = false;
                    break;
        }

        this.moveLeft ? this.positionX -= 50 : this.positionX += 50;
        this.moveUp ? this.positionY -= 25 : this.positionY += 25;

        this.rotation += 0.1;
    }
}

class MyFigure extends Figure {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    draw() {
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += `
            <div style="
                background: yellow;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                top: ${this.positionY}px;"></div>
        `;
    }

    move() { // переопределение метода
        switch(this.positionY) {

            case 500:
                    this.moveUp = true;
                    break;

                case 0:
                    this.moveUp = false;
                    break;
        }
        this.moveUp ? this.positionY -= 25 : this.positionY += 25;
    }
    
}

const figures = [ new Rect(), new Circle(), new Square(), new MyFigure ];

setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "";
    for (let figure of figures) {
        figure.move();
        figure.draw();
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Если можете помочь сократить ещё, буду только рад помощи, но дело ведь не в этом... 
код нужно дополнить а не исправить, я не понимаю, как получить данные из каждого отдельного объекта фигуры, и сравнить их между собой, дабы вычислить столкновение.

Comment: Для определения столкновений есть целые теории например http://noregret.org/tutor/n/collision/ так что полагаю что это самая основная часть задачи

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей. Посмотрю.